# TALEND... How can i send the same email INDIVIDUALLY to 400 diff people

Tags: email, jobs, talend

hi im looking at my talend jobs and trying to send the same email to 400 diff people, but i need to do it ONE AT A TIME, as opposed to all at once

what should i be looking at to complete this? iteration or looping somehow ? any references or advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: flowToIterate is your friend, and it can be executed multi-threaded if you're on enterprise, just check its advanced settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While having the email address, the subject and the body as rows I would use a tSendMail to send the mail inside a normal row loop and maybe a tSleep component to wait shortly if the email is big.

In the job settings, as stated by Balazs Gunics, you can set under "Extra" "Multi threaded execution" which, depending on your use case, can speed up the processing.